# How to check the checkbox by looping 2 arrays in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have 2 array's like the following:

```
var fullList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var dbList = ["1", "4"];
```

This is the current code.....

```
var fullList = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];
var dbList = ["1", "4"];

isCheckboxSelected = (option, $event) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < fullList.length; i++) {
        if (dbList.indexOf(option.key) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

How can we write better code using foreach (linq) in Type script ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: what are you trying to check? that selected option is in both arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
const isChecked = (option, event) => dbList.includes(option.key)
```

That is if your `option.key` is always one of the entries you have in fullList and whenever you check an item, its `option.key` is registered in dbList